Java application keeps using the wrong database, even though I specified which one to use
I was working on a college project for a Java application which uses the Swing library. Everything seemed to be going really well, but suddenly, when I used git on my university's notebook to pull the project, things started to go downhill. The problem here is I cannot make it access the correct database, even though it's already set up in this new PC's SQL Server instance. Also, I've already changed the username and password in order to have access to the SQL Server instance running on my college's notebooks. Everything seems to be as it should on both the database side and on the frontend side.
My application was supposed to access a database called "acadio", but it is currently accessing a database called "java", that was created for testing Java DB-related code. This is causing a major headache, because without the application accessing the correct database, some other parts of the code start to break. My application was supposed to show some Swing components, but all that it shows is the wrong database data.
enter image description here
I am using the Eclipse IDE with these specifications:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build id: 20230907-1323
OS: Windows 11, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java runtime version: 17.0.8.1+1
Java version: 17.0.8.1
It is also worth mentioning that I used Eclipse 2024-03 in the previous PC.
Thanks in advance!
Here's the code used to access the SQL Server database (which was supposed to be "acadio"):
package services;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class BD {

    public Connection con = null;
    public PreparedStatement st = null;
    public ResultSet rs = null;

    private final String DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private final String DATABASENAME = "acadio";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databasename=" + DATABASENAME;
        //I intentionally omitted these for StackOverflow
    private final String LOGIN = "*******";
    private final String PASSWORD = "*****"; 
    // private final String INTEGRATED_SECURITY = "true";

    /**
     * 
     * Establishes a connection with the database
     *
     * @param - none;
     * @return - true in case of success, or false otherwise
     * 
     */
    public boolean getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, LOGIN, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected successfully!");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException error) {
            System.out.println("Error connecting to the database: " + error.toString());
            return false;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException error) {
            System.out.println("Error loading the driver: " + error.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the connection and releases the objects used
     */
    public void close() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BD bd = new BD();
        bd.getConnection();
    }
}

I've tried refreshing and closing and opening my project. No good.
I've tried restarting Eclipse, also no good.
And I also tried closing other projects that were opened in my IDE to no avail.
I even tried deleting the "acadio" database and creating a new one, and still no luck.

returning 'true' on success and 'false' on failure is wrong. Exceptions are how java works. a method whose very essence (i.e. the javadoc and its signature) are already yelling out loud 'I do database things' that is not defined as throws SQLException, is broken. Note that main can (and generally should!) be declared as throws Exception.

What happens if you make that databaseName instead of databasename?

By the way… (a)  I'd suggest learning to use an implementation of DataSource to hold your server address, user name, password, etc. No need for you to recreate getConnection. (b) The need for Class.forName evaporated many years ago.

According to the JDBC # Setting the connection properties documentation the connection string property names are supposed to be case-insensitive, so using either databasename or databaseName are equivalent. Are you sure that in all the kerfuffle your original acadio database hasn't been dropped and/or replaced with a different version that no longer holds all of your old data? Can you still use SSMS or DBeaver to see all of the expected data in the original database?

Not sure if that's a valid URL. More normal would be "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/" + DATABASENAME

Agree with above speakers, the parameter is called: databaseName, but you know, even if you're stuck in some db, you can always change the database by calling: con.setCatalog("someOtherDatabase");

I just managed to fix the issue, but it still boggles me why it chooses the wrong database anyway. Basically, there were some .jar dependencies missing and I added them, then it worked normally. Again, I don't know why it does this despite nowhere in the code it mentions or tells the application to use the wrong database.
Thank you for your input anyway, I really appreciate it!
